Plasma Breeze Mozilla / Browser render problem: Gaps between app and x-container border
Between the app and x-container there is a gap which result in borders being drawn outside of the app window. This happens on Plasma 5 & 6 for flatpak and pacman apps from Mozilla and Brave (there might be more apps) on X11. Does anyone had the same problem and solved it? Thank you for any hint!

Edit: When maximized the gaps are gone
Edit 2: The problem appears also when using Brave
